# Animation on firefox doesn't work (css only)

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations

I am trying to figure out why this animation on codepen doesn't work

```
https://codepen.io/cassie-codes/full/zWJxXj/
```

in which you can find a bubble animation with 2 images. One is a background, the second one is a mask. these random bubbles should move and reveal the mask image. On chrome works, on firefox not. I can't understand if the problem is about the svg properties or something on css. Anyway that's the code

Html:

```
<div class="bgImage"></div>
<svg class="blobCont">
        <image xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=e20bc3d490c974d9ea190e05c47962f5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" mask="url(#mask)" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
            <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0">
                <g style="filter: url(#gooey)">
          <circle class="blob" cx="10%" cy="10%" r="80" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="50%" cy="10%" r="40" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="17%" cy="15%" r="70" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="90%" cy="20%" r="120" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="30%" cy="25%" r="30" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
          <circle class="blob" cx="50%" cy="60%" r="80" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="70%" cy="90%" r="10" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="90%" cy="60%" r="90" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="30%" cy="90%" r="80" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
          <circle class="blob" cx="10%" cy="10%" r="80" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="50%" cy="10%" r="20" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="17%" cy="15%" r="70" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="40%" cy="20%" r="120" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="30%" cy="25%" r="30" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
          <circle class="blob" cx="80%" cy="60%" r="80" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="17%" cy="10%" r="100" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="40%" cy="60%" r="90" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle class="blob" cx="10%" cy="50%" r="80" fill="white" stroke="white"/>
                </g>
            </mask>
            <filter id="gooey" height="130%">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" result="blur" />
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
        </filter>
    </svg>
```

scss:

```
body , .bgImage {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.bgImage {
  position: absolute;
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=e20bc3d490c974d9ea190e05c47962f5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80);
background-size: cover;
background-position: top;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(70%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(70%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.blobCont {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}




@for $i from 1 through 18 {
   $a : #{$i*90};
   $b : #{$i*90+360}; 

  .blob:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation: move#{$i} 20s infinite linear;
  }

  @keyframes move#{$i} {
    from {
      transform:rotate(#{$a}deg) translate( 200px ,0.1px) rotate(-#{$a}deg);
    }
    to {
      transform:rotate(#{$b}deg) translate( 200px ,0.1px) rotate(-#{$b}deg);
    }
  }

  }
```

and if needs, css compiled from scss

```
body, .bgImage {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bgImage {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=e20bc3d490c974d9ea190e05c47962f5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(70%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(70%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.blobCont {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.blob:nth-child(1) {
  animation: move1 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move1 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(450deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-450deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(2) {
  animation: move2 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move2 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(540deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-540deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(3) {
  animation: move3 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move3 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-270deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(630deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-630deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(4) {
  animation: move4 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move4 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(720deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-720deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(5) {
  animation: move5 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move5 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(450deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-450deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(810deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-810deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(6) {
  animation: move6 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move6 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(540deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-540deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(900deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-900deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(7) {
  animation: move7 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move7 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(630deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-630deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(990deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-990deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(8) {
  animation: move8 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move8 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(720deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-720deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1080deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1080deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(9) {
  animation: move9 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move9 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(810deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-810deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1170deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1170deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(10) {
  animation: move10 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move10 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(900deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-900deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1260deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1260deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(11) {
  animation: move11 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move11 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(990deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-990deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1350deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1350deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(12) {
  animation: move12 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move12 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1080deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1080deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1440deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1440deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(13) {
  animation: move13 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move13 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1170deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1170deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1530deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1530deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(14) {
  animation: move14 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move14 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1260deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1260deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1620deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1620deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(15) {
  animation: move15 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move15 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1350deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1350deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1710deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1710deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(16) {
  animation: move16 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move16 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1440deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1440deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1800deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1800deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(17) {
  animation: move17 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move17 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1530deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1530deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1890deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1890deg);
  }
}
.blob:nth-child(18) {
  animation: move18 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move18 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(1620deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1620deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1980deg) translate(200px, 0.1px) rotate(-1980deg);
  }
}
```

When I say that it doesn't work, I mean that the bubbles do not move. The animation doesn't work on firefox. But on chrome yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mozilla's developer page regarding CSS `transform`:

> Only elements positioned by the box model can be transformed. As a rule of thumb, an element is positioned by the box model if it has display: block.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: I tested around with various "solutions" and I didn't find anything obvious. Animating in CSS is said to be the "wrong" way to handle SVG, so try doing most of it in an svg file maybe? Also came across a guy that made animations with js instead, to work around the browser support issues..

Comment: Thank you very much Benjamin. I will try in a different way